# mySQL get average time on day change

Tags: mysql, time, average

Consider having the following two timestamps

```
"2018-07-12 23:50:00","2018-07-14 00:30:00"
```

I want to find the average `time` of both of them.

The result should be `00:10:00` as a time. (I'm not interested in the actual date in the end, just the time).

I started by comparing which one is earlier (continuous time flow) but failed. If I use the date to compare `23:50:00` (regardless which time) is always earlier because it considers the date too. If I use the time to compare `00:30` is always earlier because it just considers the time itself.

I need this later in a *trigger* with two timestamps. One currently stored (`OLD`) and the updated (`NEW`) to calculate a new average time.

Any advice is appreciated

Comment: How is 10 minutes the average of 50 minutes and 30 minutes? Can you explain more?

Comment: What do you consider a "day change", your example data is spread over three dates already. And why are you talking about "comparing" times, when you say you need an average? An average is a calculation, so where exactly does any comparison come in?

Comment: Just because you don't understand the issue there's no need to put a negative vote. From 23:50 to 00:30 there is 40min. Average this gives me 00:10. I said I don't care about the date itself, just the time matters. But without the date there is no chance in getting a correct average. Compare is the wrong word sorry...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you take the average of two `DATETIME` values you actually are computing the `DATETIME` value at the midpoint between the two input values.

Here's a way to do that averaging of two `DATETIME` values.

```
 SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME((UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-07-12 23:50:00')+UNIX_TIMESTAMP("2018-07-14 00:30:00"))2)
```

It works because Unix timestamps are actually the number of seconds since a particular time in history. They are numeric quantities and you can do arithmetic with them.

Then, if you only want the time part of the average you can use the `TIME()` function.

But, it looks like you don't actually want the numeric average of two `DATETIME` values; your examples are 24h 20m apart.  It looks like you want the average of the times *as if* the earlier datetime were on the day preceding the later datetime.

You can compute that as follows:

```
SET @startSec := TiME_TO_SEC(TIME('2018-07-12 23:50:00'));
SET @endSec := TiME_TO_SEC(TIME('2018-07-14 00:30:00'));
SET @endSec = IF(@startSec > @endSec, @endSec + TIME_TO_SEC('24:00:00'), @endSec);
SET @deltaSec := ((@startSec + @endSec) /2) MOD TIME_TO_SEC('24:00:00') ;
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(@deltaSec);
```

The trick to handling the *as if* condition is the `IF()` function call.

This is a big enough pain to write in SQL that it may make sense for you to create a stored function to handle it.

Comment: Thank you for understanding my logic! Much appreciated!